# Regular Insert vs Insert with Select Statement : SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know if the following queries are same or not and if not, then what is the difference between them ?

**Query 1 :**

```
Insert into TableA
select col1,col2 from TableB
```

**Query 2 :**

```
insert into TableA
values (val1,val2)

insert into TableA
values (val3,val4)
```

Moreover, i would also like to know that eventually **Query 1** will be inserting row one by one which is not equivalent to bulk insert, am i right ?

Comment: Isn't it obvious what's the difference between them? First one will insert the data into `TableA` by selecting it from another table such as `TableB`, second query(ies) actually directly insert the data into the `TableA`. At the end, they will both insert data to `TableA`, but one of them grabs them from the database while the other is hardcoded values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TableB` has only two records, and both the `(val1, val2)` pairs match the literal values you specified using `VALUES`, then the two queries are equivalent.  So the answer is that the inserts may, or may not, be the same, depending on the underlying data.

Comment: @shujaatsiddiqui Your updated question does not really change my answer, which is about as close as anyone is going to get without you showing us actual data.

Comment: If you have actual data, then we can have a closer look.

Comment: no it is just POC. Please make me correct if i am wrong that both will not be considered as bulk insert right ?

Comment: No, neither are SQL Server's bulk insert tool.  And both of these options exist across most SQL databases, so such code would be relatively portable.